# How to remove x86_64 architechture from libWebRTC.a static library while building fat library from this static library in iOS?

Tags: ios, architecture, sdk, frameworks, webrtc

[image: Shows this error while creating a fat library using libWebRTC.a static library]

Shows this error while creating a fat library using libWebRTC.a static library

Till yet I found that this architecture is for Simulator and WebRTC.a static library has some known issue with this while building the fat library.

Comment: Try to re-install pods..

Comment: I am not using pods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I faced this issue while I was creating a fat(Multiplatform) framework
>   using libWebRTC.a static library. Having some research I found that
>   its a know issue of webrtc library of architecture support for
>   simulator.

*And I found that to fix it I have to remove this architecture from this static library... This is what I did and fixed it.*

```
//lipo <static library file name> -remove <arch_name> <Output file name>

lipo libWebRTC.a  -remove x86_64 -output libWebRTC_arm7.a
```

Mentioning that this command is running on the folder where the file is located.

I have invested a lots of effort and frustration to solve this. Hope some one else can save their's.

Comment: thanks so much this was a life saver, couldn't get my app to build on App Center with my static library for last 2 days!! Tried everything else possible, this was the only thing that managed to fix it for my distribution build.